# What's the most frequent error? NRQL Query

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, nrql

I'm trying to figure out how to use New Relic Query Builder and I having trouble with this query:

What's the most frequent error?

I tried :

> `SELECT level FROM Log WHERE level='error' AND rate(level)`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what structure of **Log** do you have and which resulting view would you like to receive, could you please provide structure so it's possible to provide you NRQL.

As a general basic solution, you can try **FACET**

It shows the most frequent error level and occurrences

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Log FACET level LIMIT 1
```

It shows the most frequent error level 1 minute rate

```
SELECT rate(count(*), 1 minute) FROM Log FACET level LIMIT 1
```

If you have an error message/type inside **Log**, then it makes sense to **FACET** by that type (use field name which is specified in your **Log**)

```
SELECT rate(count(*), 1 minute) FROM Log WHERE level='error' FACET type LIMIT 1
```